# how to enable and store the data in EMMC memory chip

Tags: usb, memory, spartan-6

I'm working on a board which has an FPGA, USB controller, EMMC memory chip and a USB 3.0 connector. Now the data has to be transferred from the host PC through USB 3.0. From the USB controller the data is received by FPGA and further stored in EMMC(NAND flash) memory. I don't have the specific programming set for enabling the EMMC chip. I request you to suggest how to overcome this problem. The details of the components are mentioned below.

- FPGA: Spartan 6
- EMMC: MTFC8GAKAJCN-4M IT TR

waiting for the reply from you...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i'm working on a EMMC memory chip, but in data sheet they have no mentioned how to program the chip, how to keep the chip in write mode and read mode. i want this data sir